# Excel::Writer::XLSX: Some cells in passed worksheet cannot be written to

Tags: excel, perl, xlsx

I a single workbook and I am hoping to pass it to various subs, each of which writes to the same worksheet. The first sub will create the worksheet and write a few columns, and the others will add more columns and fill the cells in those columns. What I am observing is that some cells cannot be written to by the other subs as shown below:

```
sub SubOne
{
    my ($workbook) = @_;

    my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet("Startup");
    my $formatHead = $workbook->add_format();
    $formatHead->set_bold();
    $formatHead->set_align('center');
    $formatHead->set_bg_color('yellow');

    my $formatContents = $workbook->add_format();
    $formatContents->set_align('center');

    $worksheet->set_tab_color('Red');
    $worksheet->set_column('A:A', 11);
    $worksheet->set_column('B:B', 15);
    $worksheet->set_column('C:C', 15);
    $worksheet->set_column('D:D', 24);
    $worksheet->write(0, 0, "column0", $formatHead);
    $worksheet->write(0, 1, "column1", $formatHead);
    $worksheet->write(0, 2, "column2", $formatHead);
    $worksheet->write(0, 3, "column3", $formatHead);
    #Fill the columns with data
}
```

This all works great. Four columns are created with headings and have data in them. Let's say there are 3 rows of data under each column. That all works fine. Then another sub is called like the following as an example:

```
sub SubTwo
{
    my ($workbook) = @_;

    my $worksheet3 = $workbook->sheets(0);

    my $formatHead = $workbook->add_format();
    $formatHead->set_bold();
    $formatHead->set_align('center');
    $formatHead->set_bg_color('yellow');

    my $formatContents = $workbook->add_format();
    $formatContents->set_align('center');

    $worksheet3->write(0, 4, "column4", $formatHead );
    $worksheet3->write(0, 5, "column5", $formatHead );
    $worksheet3->write(6, 6, "test1", $formatContents);
    $worksheet3->write(7, 7, "test2", $formatHead);
    $worksheet3->write(1, 8, "test3", $formatHead);
    $worksheet3->write(7, 1, "test4", $formatContents);
}
```

Out of these, only test1, test2, test4 are written. They are in the correct cells. It is as if nothing can be written to the rows that have been written to by the previous sub SubOne. Why would the rows be locked from further writing?

EDIT: Fix was turning set_optimization() off.

Comment: Most likely it is because Excel::Writer::XLSX writes the data out directly and Excel does not overwrite data when reading information for a cell where it already has data. So, ideally, you build your output data model before handing it to Excel::Writer::XLSX.

Comment: I used your example code and opened the resulting file in LibreOffice. Everything looks as expected here.

Comment: I could not reproduce either.

Comment: Turned out the issue was set_optimization() was on when the workbook was created.